# C# freeze while starting batch stream

Tags: c#, process

Hey people! I am working with my little tool called MineMe, and it is used to handle Minecraft servers.

So i made a file stream, that should stream the output of the start_base.cmd (the file that starts the server). What goes wrong, is that the window with my form freezes, until i kill the process (java.exe - Ran by start_base.cmd)

Here is my code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("CMD");

        processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = processInfo;
        p.Start();

        TextWriter tw = p.StandardInput;


        tw.Flush();
        tw.WriteLine("start_base.cmd");
        tw.Close();

        TextReader tr = p.StandardOutput;
        string output = tr.ReadLine();

        while (output != null)
        {
            this.lg_log.Items.Add(output); // add the output string to a list box
            output = tr.ReadLine();
        }
```

What's wrong here? :) Please help me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your UI thread start another thread to process the while loop:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoWork));
t.Start();


public void DoWork()
{
    // work to be done on another thread
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your `while` loop.  You need to do this on a separate thread (i.e. not your UI thread).

If you're calling the above code from a button click (or some other UI control), you should instead use a BackgroundWorker thread or a thread from the thread pool (or even just a plain vanilla Thread) for this task.

Comment: Sorry :) I don't think i understand you - Could you please edit the code? :D

Comment: @Frederik: the answer from `tzup` shows the "plain vanilla Thread" approach, and it will work fine for your purposes. Here's a link that shows how to use a `ThreadPool` thread: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx#Y440

Comment: And here's how to use a `BackgroundWorker` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx